# How to get the background color of the view from inside an Embedded View

Tags: swift

And Thanks in advance for any help.

I have a an embedded view that I want to load in multiple ViewControllers. this is working fine. The problem comes when I try to get the background color of the main View.
[Image is VC setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vel1N.png)

So I have tried all sorts. I thought about using userDefaults and save the color when the main VC loads and get the colour from userDefaults in the embedded VC, but this feels like a bit of a hack.

The Code below obviously will only get the colour of the view in the embedded VC. Im thinking there must be away to check superview or something?

```
 if self.view.backgroundColor!.isEqual(UIColor.White) {
        print("Background is White")
    } else {
        print("not White")
    }
```

I hope this makes sense. Again Thanks in advance for any enlightenment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this if it's the root

```
if let roo = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController { 
    print(roo.view.backgroundColor)
    if roo.view.backgroundColor == .white {
      print("Yes")
    }
    else {
      print("No")
    }
}
```

---

if not You can also create a delegate like

```
class ChildVC: UIViewController {
   weak var delegate:ParentVC?
}
```

and in `viewDidLoad` of parent

```
if let fir = self.children.first as? ChildVC {
    fir.delegate = self 
}
```

After that you can get the parent color with

```
delegate?.view.backgroundColor
```

Comment: this works and returns `UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.223529 0.541176 0.709804 1` but im comparing it to this.. `UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.22 0.54 0.71 1`